# Try to add product to opencart featured module but products are not appearing

Tags: opencart2.x

I have created a product. After creating it I want to add this product to featured module so that it will appear in home page. But product is not showing in dropdown of product list. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Rakesh, It's autocomplete drop-down product listing. when you click on product text box then it will show products or you will also type name of product so it will give you result of products. 
Or it still not showing result then you will check Ajax response in console browser.

Comment: Thanks problem solved

Comment: Good. then give whote and tick mark to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should `click` here otherwise the `AJAX` will not run.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Featured module is autocomplete drop-down product listing. When you click on product text box then after it will show you list of available products. You will also able type name of product so it will show you result of available products. 
**Note:** If it still not showing result then you will check Ajax response in console browser.